# dataset.drop_duplicates() gives ValueError: Wrong number of items passed, but sample(frac=1) doesn't

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset called work3 that I'm trying to drop the duplicate rows based on the 'clean_name' column. Below is info about work3:

```
work3.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3295520 entries, 0 to 3330947
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id            int64
name          object
address       object
clean_name    object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 276.7+ MB
```

and when I try the drop_duplicates, it brings me a ValueError:

```
work3.drop_duplicates(['clean_name'])
```

output:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2117463, placement implies 3295520
```

Now, if I try to sample it, but make frac = 1, to take the entire dataset and then check the info:

```
test = work3.sample(frac=1)
test.info()
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3295520 entries, 419298 to 978722
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id            int64
name          object
address       object
clean_name    object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 125.7+ MB
```

..the memory usage is about half as much! 125.7+ MB instead of 276.7+ MB.
More importantly, when I do the drop_duplicates function on it:

```
test.drop_duplicates(['clean_name'))
```

it gives me what I want without any errors! Am I missing something here?

```
2117463 rows × 4 columns
```

To sum up, here are my questions:

1. Why was the memory usage reduced by half, even though it's the exact same dataset?
2. why does the sample, test.drop_duplicates(), work without an error, but the original dataset, work 3, give me a ValueError??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a duplicated index. This error doesn't get thrown when using `.sample` because your dataframe gets re-indexed. Reindex first:

```
work3.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates(['clean_name'])
```

Comment: Super useful this is :D